# Registration Forms

Tags: plugin-development

My current WP configuration

Theme used: Hope
Extensions in place: Easy Registration Forms, Gravity Forms
Website address: https://fegu.org

Problem (s) encountered: I am developing a mini site that will allow students to enroll (register) and send me their report cards; however, once a student is registered in my database, I would like him to be able to automatically receive a registration code, so when sending his report card he will simply be asked to first enter his registration code (the latter contains this information, name, first name .......). once he enters the registration code, he has the option to send his ballot.

Please, I have not been able to do this for almost two weeks. I did not do it with Gravity Forms, no results, I did it with Easy Forms (https://fegu.org/enrolement/) like I really need you.

Thank you!

Comment: Let us know what all steps have you implemented so far. if possible show the code snippet for the same.

Comment: Thank you for posting, but unfortunately third party plugins and themes are out of scope here at WPSE. In terms of WP core functionality, you might be able to leverage the [`user_register`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) hook to trigger the sending of the registration code.